# how to select multiple rows from database using php and then populate drop down list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have selected rows from database using PHP by using following code but doesn't seem to work.

```
    // selection
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, id FROM branch");

    $staff = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $staff[] = $row['id']['name'];
}
```

here is my dropdown which upon selection triggers another dropdown list

```
  <select id="branch" name="branch"  onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('anotherdropdown'))">
  </select>

  <select id="anotherdropdown" name="anotherdropdown">
  </select>
```

here is javascript for it

```
    function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,branch) {

    // the array_staff contains array data received from database
    var array_staff = <?= json_encode($staff) ?>;
}
```

using switch statement i want to send id and name to 'createoption' function to create dropdownlist with value = "id"

```
   switch (ddl1.value) {
     case '2':
         branch.options.length = 0;
         for (i = 0; i < array_staff.length; i++) {
             createOption(branch, array_staff['name'], array_staff['id']);
         }
         break;
         default:
             branch.options.length = 0;
         break;
    }
    }
    function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
     var opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = value;
     opt.text = text;
     ddl.options.add(opt);
    }
    </script>
```

I hope i explained it well. Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: shouldn't this yield an error? `$row['id']['name']`

Comment: `$row['id']` and `$row['name']` would be the separate columns. You could do `$staff[] = array($row['id'], $row['name'])`.

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks, that worked. now how do i use that data to create <options> using the JavaScript function. Currently I'm using 

for (i = 0; i < array_staff.length; i++) {
             createOption(branch, array_staff['name'], array_staff['id']);
         }